# How to use Numerical URLs Instead of slug for tags & Categories?

Tags: wordpress, url, tags, categories

I have a question concerning both tags and categories, I'd like to change the url structure from

"Mywebsite/tags/TagSlug" & "Mywebsite/tags/CatSlug"

To "Mywebsite/tags/TagId" & "Mywebsite/tags/CatId"

Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress Plugin to Generate non-numeric slug / permalink for posts without titles? (1 post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466484/wordpress-plugin-to-generate-non-numeric-slug-permalink-for-posts-without-titl)